# How do I use a asp:timer to time actions happening inside a button click event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer

I have an application that allows a user to save a record to the database. When The user clicks save I want to show a label that says **Saving record please wait...** then after 3 seconds I want the label to say **Record Saved**. Finally after 3 more seconds I want to go back to the normal view. Here is hat I tried:

```
txtSaveReportAs.Enabled = false;
strSaveNotify = "lblWarning";
lblSaveAs.Text = "Saving Your Data. Please Wait... ";
System.Windows.Forms.Timer Timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
Timer1.Interval = 3000;
Timer1.Start();
strSaveNotify = "lblSuccess";
lblSaveAs.Text = "Data Saved Successfully";
Timer1.Stop();
Timer1.Interval = 3000;
Timer1.Start();
txtSaveReportAs.Enabled = true;
txtSaveReportAs.Text = string.Empty;
```

When I do this it cancels out my `sqlCommand` so `txtSaveReporAs` just does not become disabled. Also, strSaveNotify and lblSaveReport as does not change and no info gets saved to the database. How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Timer like a Sleep, which halts execution within the current thread - not that I am suggesting you replace it with a Sleep, because they should only be used in limited circumstances and this is not one.

For the Timer to work it needs an Tick event handler added to it. The event handler gets triggered when when the timer has completed the 3 seconds.  You don't call Stop() in the same set of code, because this will turn it off immediately after you have turned it on.  Processing doesn't stop and wait where you have Timer1.Start(), it keeps going.

You need to look up the specifications for the Timer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick(v=vs.110).aspx